Batching inference for llama
I am using llama3.1:8b for answering questions based on given context. Doing this iteratively for 20,000 takes too much time. Is there any batching solution for single gpu?
I am using it through ollama.chat which takes around 25 seconds for one generation. I want to fasten the process with same model.

if you're using Python, you can try multiprocessing.Pool to send concurrent requests to your Ollama, but don't forget to set the environment variables related to the concurrency config of your Ollama service in advance(OLLAMA_NUM_PARALLEL,OLLAMA_MAX_QUEUE).
